# change image into div when clicked, and change back to img when clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So as the title explains, I'm trying to change my image into a div(with text) when I click on the image. And when I click on the div I want it to change back to the image. I've tried certain things but none of it works. My code at the moment looks like this

```
images.click(function() {

            })
```

I need a function that changes the image into a div and also changes it back when I click on the div.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to "change" the tags? Can you use an `img` and `div` and show and hide them respectively?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. At the very least show us your HTML and what JQuery you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

just create one div as wrapper of image and div you want to show after clicking the image. like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <img src="" id="yourImage"></img>
   <div id="divYouWantToShow">
   </div>
</div>
```

then use some style to hide div so the image can be only visible.

```
#divYouWantToShow{
  display:none;
}
```

after that all You have to do is JQuery. after clicking image, image will hide and divYouWantToShow will show, simple as that:

```
$('#yourImage').click(function(){
   $(this).hide(function(){
      $('#divYouWantToShow').show();
   });
});
```

and the same if you click on div

```
$('#divYouWantToShow').click(function(){
   $(this).hide(function(){
      $('#yourImage').show();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the image and a div inside a wrapper and toggle the z-index:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#wrp', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('textTop');
});
```

```css
#wrp {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  position: relative;
}
img,
#imgAlt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

img { z-index: 10 }

#imgAlt {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 5;
}

#wrp.textTop #imgAlt { z-index: 15 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrp">
  <img src="http://www.pixeldecor.com/patterns/color-samples/brikbrak-sample.gif" />
  <div id="imgAlt">Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="id">DIV</div>
```

**java Script**

```
$(document).on('click','#id',function(){

    var elementType = $(this).prop('tagName');
    if(elementType.toLowerCase() == 'div'){
        var image = '<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" id="id">';
        $(this).remove();
        $('body').append(image);
    }
    else{
        var div = '<div id="id">DIV</div>';
        $(this).remove();
        $('body').append(div);
    }

});
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9wkmx65h/)